# Button Color and Logo Color are Shared Making for Funky Magnet

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

In [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler), there is a button that shows all rooms with our logo on it. It looks like this:

> [image: button screenshot]

As you can see, the bottom right of the icon is the same color as the button background, making our logo look like a funky magnet. Or a claw from one of those claw crane games where you try to snag prizes.

(this is not a serious issue)

Comment: it is a hint that chat room has to be renamed to _Funky Magnet_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're going to use a darker blue for the chatroom button background color so the logo doesn't show up as a magnet. The change will go live after our next production build.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the prize IS getting into the chat rooms...